# insert a space in line after notepad++

Tags: notepad++

i've this url

`https://www.mirrored.to/files/12345678/abcdefgh`

and I need to change this replace the / with space before the a alphabet 2 Space

`https://www.mirrored.to/files/12345678  abcdefgh`

Comment: https://regex101.com/ and Notepad++'s search and replace function.

Comment: I found two spaces. Do you want to replace the last `/` by one space or two spaces? [Edit] your question and improve formatting for better reading. e.g. four blanks at beginning of text (code) lines.

Comment: @help-info.de Teach a man to fish...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `/(?!.*/)`
- Replace with:     # 2 spaces
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
/           # a slash
(?!.*/)     # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't another slash after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU THIS WORKS

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have your single URL or some more in a text file line by line

```
https://www.mirrored.to/files/12345678/abcdefgh
https://superuser.com/questions/1807813/insert-a-space-in-line-after-notepad
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76245266/adding-characters-to-the-first
https://www.mirrored.to/files/12345678/ABCDEFGH
```

you'd go through following steps:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+\d)(\/)(.+$)`
- Replace with: `$1  $3`
- Tick the *Wrap around* option
- Search mode: *Regular expression*
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd> (at your own risk)

**Explanation:**

```
^ asserts position at start of a line
1st Capturing Group (.+\d)
    .     # matches any character (except for line terminators)
    +     # matches the previous token between one and unlimited times
    \d    # matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
2nd Capturing Group (\/)
    \/    # matches the character /

3rd Capturing Group (.+$)
    .     # matches any character (except for line terminators)
    +     # matches the previous token between one and unlimited times
    $     # asserts position at the end of a line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]